# LuaLaTeX for dummies: how to add LaTeX macros into \directlua?

Tags: luatex, lua

How to make the following code to compile?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}{\directlua{for i = 1, 10 do tex.sprint(i\hskip1cm) end}}     %does not work
%\newcommand*{\mycommand}{\directlua{for i = 1, 10 do tex.sprint(i\\hskip1cm) end}}   %does not work
%\newcommand*{\mycommand}{\directlua{for i = 1, 10 do tex.sprint(i) end}}             %works 

\begin{document}
test \mycommand
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you want to concatenate the value of the variable `i` with the token `\hskip1cm`, but the expression `i\hskip1cm` is not a valid lua expression. What you need is to make `\hskip1cm` a lua string and concatenate it with the value of `i`. That is:

```
tex.sprint(i .. "\hskip1cm")
```

This, however, won't work either because inside the quotes, the `\` is a escape-char for lua, so `\h` will be interpreted as a escape sequence, and lua will complain that `\h` is an invalid escape sequence. So you have to "escape the escape":

```
tex.sprint(i .. "\\hskip1cm")
```

This would be ok for lua, but causes problems to TeX, since it makes `\\` to appear inside a tex definition, and TeX tries to expand it, causing trouble.

You can avoid this trouble in two different ways:

### First solution

This is the preferred one. Move your lua code to an external file. For example, create a file called `mycommand.lua`, which contains a lua function implementing your code:

```
-- mycommand.lua
function mycommand()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        tex.sprint(i .. "\\hskip1cm")
    end
end
```

Then, in your `tex` file, run the lua file (which defines that function and makes it available for lua), and define `\mycommand` to execute the function `mycommand`. This way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("mycommand.lua")}  % This defines the lua function mycommand()

\newcommand*{\mycommand}{\directlua{mycommand()}} % This defines the tex macro
\begin{document}
test \mycommand
\end{document}
```

Note that the expansion of `\mycommand` does not contain now any `\\`, so TeX is happy. When TeX expands `\mycommand`, this causes the function `mycommand()` to be executed, and this will "output" into the tex document the concatenation of `i.."\\hskip1cm"`, which results into `1\hskip1cm2\hskip1cm3\hskip1cm` etc, which is ok. The resulting pdf shows the intended result:

[image: result]

### Second solution

This is uglier and in general not recommended. You can put any tex macro inside `\luatexluaescapestring`, and this will modify its expansion so that the result is a valid lua string. So, if you write for example `"\luatexluaescapestring{\foo}"` this will produce a complex string which contains the expansion of `\foo`, but wich each `\` escaped as `\\`. Applying this to your example:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\newcommand*{\mycommand}{%
  \directlua{for i = 1, 10 do tex.sprint(i .. "\luatexluaescapestring{\hskip1cm}") end}
}
\begin{document}
test \mycommand
\end{document}
```

Note how you still require double quotes around it, to get a lua string which can be concatenated to the value of variable `i`.

Comment: If the package `luacode` is loaded, the turgid `"\luatexluaescapestring{\hskip1cm}"` may be replaced with the more concise `\luastring{\hskip1cm}`.

Answer (score 6):

For solution 1 above, to avoid backslash escape, I suggest to use the bracket version of lua string (the number of = characters can be any number provided you use the same twice) :

```
-- mycommand.lua
function mycommand()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        tex.sprint(i .. [===[\hskip1cm]===])
    end
end
```

If someone with enough reputation can reply this to the answer, please do so.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think this is a useful suggestion that's good enough to be an answer on its own.

Answer (score 1):

One can put all together in one file for small parts of `lua` code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
    function mycommand()
        for i = 1, 10 do
            tex.sprint(i .. "\\hskip1cm")
        end
    end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand*{\mycommand}{\directlua{mycommand()}}

\begin{document}
test \mycommand
\end{document}
```